# Dynamically change the positionof PopupWindow in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-popupwindow

I want to change position of **PopupWindow** dynamically.
Have used the following method:

```
public void showAtLocation (View parent, int gravity, int x, int y)
```

But sometime PopupWindow shows out of screen. So which relative parameter should I use for changing the value x and y (like layout height or width etc)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
public void update(int x, int y, int width, int height)
```

metod in PopupWindow

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
 dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();



wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
wmlp.x = 100;   //x position
wmlp.y = 100;   //y position

dialog.show();
```

where X and Y are in pixels.

If you just want to move the alert dialog down, then

`alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes().verticalMargin = 0.2F;`

Comment: Thank you for your response Aniruddha, But In my program the x and y values assign dynamically, so user perspective they just know give two integer value two x & y. if they put x=500 , y =750 then the popup display outside the screen . so hoe can i overcome the situation when the user use different screen size android device.